# Using default fill colors from ggplot2 graphs via annotate in R

Tags: r, graph, colors, ggplot2, visualization

I would like to access the default line or fill colors from ggplot2 and I am not sure how to do this.  Specifically, in the code below, you will see **green4**, **blue4**, and **red4** being used in the annotations.  These are my *approximations* to what I think `ggplot2` is using.

Further, if this code is not following best practices or could benefit from an alternative method, please advise.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(data.frame(x = c(0, 1000)), aes(x)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, geom = "density", args = list(mean = 200, sd = 50), 
                aes(color="technology", fill="technology", alpha= 0.75)) + 
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, geom = "density", args = list(mean = 500, sd = 200), 
                aes(color="textiles", fill="textiles", alpha = 0.75)) +
  stat_function(fun = dnorm, geom = "density", args = list(mean = 750, sd = 100), 
                aes(color="pharmaceuticals", fill="pharmaceuticals", alpha = 0.75)) + 
  labs(list(title="Fictious 'Density' Returns by Industry", x=NULL, y=NULL, color="Industry")) +
  theme(legend.position="none") +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank()) +
  annotate("text", label="technology", x=275, y=0.008, color="green4") +
  annotate("text", label="textiles", x=500, y=0.0025, color="blue4") +
  annotate("text", label="pharmaceuticals", x=835, y=0.0045, color="red4")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `ggplot_build` , to see what happen behind the scene:

```
 unique(sapply(ggplot_build(p)$data,'[[','colour'))
   [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "#00BA38" "#619CFF" "#F8766D"

 unique(sapply(ggplot_build(p)$data,'[[','fill'))
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]     
[1,] "#00BA38" "#619CFF" "#F8766D"
```

Comment: Thanks - I actually had to add another `sapply( ... , unique)` to avoid grabbing all 101 elements of each list label.